# Windows - Possible to develop a global right-click menu item

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, right-click

I'm attempting to create a menu item, which is essentially like a global clipboard. A user would be able to right click, and then hover over the menu item, and then select from the sub-menu items the selections he wants to paste, **no matter what application he's at** (if that's not possible, I'm willing to accept it being available on some applications).

First, in Windows, I see how lot of programs, such as Anti-viruses, are given a right click menu item after they are installed:

[image]

As seen above, VeriFace, Sandboxie, and McAfee were all able to add a menu item. How do they add that?

Second, if what I'm trying to make is possible to achieve, what are some resources for me to effectively hook into the Windows buffer and clipboard and have access to it everywhere?

In Android mobile OS, they have a global clipboard, where if you press the clipboard button from keyboard, the clipboard comes up, no matter what Application or process the screen currently is on:

[image]

I understand that in Windows, sometimes the right-click menu is only limited and defined by the process it's in. For example, when you right click while in Chrome, the right click menu is different than when you're on the desktop home screen or other processes.

In Microsoft Word, there is a clipboard that saves all the copied photos and texts, but it is either saved or destroyed as soon as the process is closed, and can't be used outside of the process.

The above two paragraphs are leading me to believe that what I'm trying to make isn't possible, but I know very little about accessing kernel stuff.

If my intent isn't clear enough, I can create a demo mock right-click menu that shows how a user would use it. Like McAfee has a menu item, my application would have a default menu item, and this menu item would contain sub menu items, and I could click on one of them to paste to the current process my screen is on.

Comment: What you are looking for is a Shell Context Menu handler, and their creation can be somewhat involved. Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There is a whole genre of software dedicated to this. google "clipboard replacement"

Comment: @Yorik thanks for the suggestion. I wanted to make my own, as a personal project

Comment: if you are looking for coding device, check stack overflow. The only question I see in your post is "is this possible?" I would suggest asking more along hte lines of "where should I start reading about context menus and hooking into the clipboard"

Comment: @Yorik you're correct. Your comment indicates that the app I'm trying to make is indeed possible